# Losing Spring @Value("${}") when instantiate class

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.1.3 (Embedded Tomcat)` + `Thymeleaf 3.0` + `Java 8`.

I have a simple class like this:

```
@Data
public class Machine {
   private Integer price;
   @Value("${settings.default}")
   private String settings;
}
```

And a simple `application.properties`:

```
settings.default=deafult
```

But when I instantiate the class anyway in the code:

```
Machine m = new Machine();
System.out.println(m.getSettings);
```

It returns null. Obviuosly if I do:

```
@Data
public class Machine {
   private Integer price;
   private String settings = "Default";
}
```

It works.. Or if I use that value inside a class method it works again.
What's wrong? Can I do something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class should be declared with stereotype annotations to use `@Value`

```java
@Component
public class Machine {
   private Integer price;
   @Value("${settings.default}")  
   private String settings;
}
```

And of course you have to autowire the Machine class (Spring has defined the bean),  instantiating a new Object will not get the value, so to use

```java
@Service
public class FooService {
  @Autowire
  private Machine machine;

  public void fooMethod() {
    System.out.println(machine.getSettings()); // default
  }
}
```